# Angular 2 (mouseleave) isn't called on fast mouse move

Tags: angular, typescript, mouseleave

In my Angular 2 app, I have a canvas. When someone hovers over certain parts, I display a popover with information. When they mouse away from the popover, I use the (mouseleave) event on the popover to hide the popover and and change up some variables in my typescript.

However, I've found a problem in my testing. When you hover over something and display the popover, and then very quickly move off the popover, mouseleave never fires.

Here is a plunker that replicates the issue (a simplified version): https://plnkr.co/edit/5I2Nm6Rj0BESMgXstCFa?p=preview

```
this example uses (mouseleave)
```

How to replicate the issue: hover over the blue dot, and then move your mouse pointer away from the popup to the right at a slow/normal speed. The popover will disappear as expected, because mouseleave is called. Now try it again, except jerk your mouse pointer off to the right very fast. It might take you a couple tries, but if you move it fast enough, mouseleave will never fire.

Is this a bug? Is there an easy way to fix this, or something I can use in place of mouseleave?

Comment: I may have a fast pc, or a slow mouse, but I cannot reproduce this behaviour

Comment: I do it like Usain Bolt but can't reproduce

Comment: It's hard to repro. You have to get the hang of it. Let me see if I can create a video or gif of this happening. Note, my computer does run slow sometimes, but this should still work regardless of lag.

Comment: https://youtu.be/EvpdhhLSBTY it took me a couple tries, but at 26 seconds in, I finally tripped it up.

Comment: I am also testing with Windows 10 in Chrome 58.0.3029.110

Comment: I reproduce this easily, just go from left to right (it works with normal gesture speed) passing through the dot. I get the problem almost 10% of the time